# bash script to make folders with names from 00 to ff

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I want to make folders with names from 00 to ff(total 256 folders) such that each of them again have folders with names from 00 to ff. What should I write on my terminal?Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`printf` can format a series of numbers as hex:

```
mkdir $(printf "%02x " {0..255})

for dir in */
do
  mkdir $(printf "$dir/%02x " {0..255})
done
```

Comment: how can i have in each of these folders again folders with names from 00 to ff

Comment: In lieu of a clever solution, use a for loop

Comment: @thatotherguy: `mkdir -p $(printf "%04x " {0..65535} | sed 's/\(..\)\(..\) /\1\/\2 /g')`

Answer (score 2):

Borrowing the core idea from the answer from @thatotherguy.

```
dirs=$(printf "%02x " {0..255})
for d1 in $dirs
do
   mkdir d1
   for d2 in $dirs
   do
      mkdir d1/d2
   done
done
```

Answer (score 1):

`for x in {{0..9},{a..f}}{{0..9},{a..f}}; do mkdir -p $x/{{0..9},{a..f}}{{0..9},{a..f}}; done`

This will make 256 directories, each with 256 subdirectories, for a total of 65,536 subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

My version using different commands:

```
join -j2  <(seq 0 255) <(seq 0 255) | xargs -n256 printf "%02x/%02x\n" | xargs mkdir -p
```